# drupal 7 - wiki page

Tags: drupal, wiki, drupal-modules, drupal-7

Is there a module or a way to simulate a wiki page for some users role in Drupal 7 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the module called Organic Group (usually called OG) you can create wiki pages. http://drupal.org/project/og

OG is creating the notion of group post which can be standard group post (only the author can edit a page) or the wiki group post (every member of the group can edit the page).

Otherwise Drupal is able to use revisions, you can use that to allow your users to edit the content.

Comment: While Organic Groups does provide wiki functionality, it does *WAY* more than just add a wiki to your site. Unless you're looking for all the groupware features, you may want to look into upgrading some of the Drupal 6 modules for building a wiki site intead: http://openconcept.ca/blog/ethan/creating_a_drupal_6_wiki/drupal